# Python: Implicit conversion of object to str?

Tags: python, string, class, types

Given the following code

```
class A:
  def __init__(self ):
    self.b = B()

  def __repr__(self):
    #return "<A with {} inside>".format( self.b )
    #return "<A with " + repr(self.b) + " inside>"
    return "<A with " + self.b  + " inside>" # TypeError: Can't convert 'B' object to str implicitly

class B:
  def __repr__(self):
    return "<B>"

a = A()
print(a)
```

I am wondering why B's `__repr__` is not called when "adding" A's `self.b` to a string.

- [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

Comment: For the same reason that `"three " + 3` fails. Is there a way to have the object behave as a string?

Comment: Yes, **explicitly** convert it to a string, using `str` or `repr`, or use string formatting: `"<A with {!r} inside>".format(self.b)`. Python is **strongly typed**, implicit conversion doesn't happen.

Comment: OK, so there's no such thing like Ruby's operator overloading (which I had in the back of my head).

Comment: What if you use str.format rather than concatenating the strings?

Comment: Both commented lines (format() and repr()) do the conversion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you turn you comment into an answer so I can "accept" it ?

Comment: @handle it appears to already *be* an answer!

Comment: To put it in another way, Python *fortunately* is not PHP ;)

Comment: @handle operator overrides are a thing - it wouldn't be a good way to work here, but you *can* do it. It'd also rely on you doing the "adding" in a particular order (or rather you'd have to have a string after your "B". So yeah, not a good idea.

Comment: Python does support right-hand-side operator overloading too, so you could make it act like a string in a lot of ways.  I'm not sure whether or not those ways would completely encompass the uses of implicit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenation doesn't cause `self.b` to be evaluated as a string. You need to explicitly tell Python to coerce it into a string.

You could do:

```
return "<A with " + repr(self.b)  + " inside>"
```

But using `str.format` would be better.

```
return "<A with {} inside>".format(self.b)
```

However as jonrsharpe points out that would try to call `__str__` first (if it exists), in order to make it specifically use `__repr__` there's this syntax: `{!r}`.

```
return "<A with {!r} inside>".format(self.b)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use repr()

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = repr(B())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<A with " + self.b + " inside>"


class B:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<B>"

a = A()
print(repr(a))
```

its works for me

Comment: This might technically produce the output required but it means that `self.b` is just set to a string instead of an object.